# Check My Code. Is it a correct way to append?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

```
function saveToDataBase(save_id,textarea_id,question_no,assg_name,testinput,testoutput)
{
    document.getElementById(save_id).addEventListener('click',function(){

        //alert("Hello");
        var question=document.getElementById(textarea_id).value;
        var question_id=assignment_name+question_no;
        var request;
        var url="saveQuesToDataBase.jsp?question="+question+"&question_id="+question_id+"&assg_name="+assg_name;

        for(var i=0;i<testinput.length;i++)
            {
              var v=document.getElementById(testinput[i]).value;
              url=url+"&testinput"+i+"="+v;
            }

        for(var i=0;i<testoutput.length;i++)
            {
              var v=document.getElementById(testoutput[i]).value;
              url=url+"&testoutput"+i+"="+v;
            }

        var len=testinput.length;
        url=url+"&size_of_arr="+len;

        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {  
        request=new XMLHttpRequest();  
        }
        else if(window.ActiveXObject)
        {  
        request=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
        }    
        try
        {  
        request.onreadystatechange=function()
        {  
        if(request.readyState==4 && request.status == 200)
        {  
            alert(request.responseText);
        }  
        };
        request.open("GET",url,true);  
        request.send();  
        }
        catch(e){alert("Unable to connect to server");
        }
    })

}
```

The function is called on click, but not redirected to saveQuesToDataBase.jsp . Please see if I could append things to url this way ? Tell me the better way.

testinput and testoutput are the two arrays of id's of textareas.
I used loop to retrieve id and to get the value.

Comment: `Get` will have query parameter length limit,so it's a bad for your code design

Comment: Please suggest me a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your code design,I have two suggestions:

a. First I would recommend you using **[`jQuery ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)** instead of original `Ajax`,it will hide the implement of different browsers.With it you can make it like below:

```
$.ajax({
  url:your_request_url,
  type:"post",//or get
  data:your data,
  success:function(data){},
  error:function(){}
});
```

b. since `Http Get` method has parameter length limit,details can be found at **[maximum length of HTTP GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request)**. You need to use `POST` instead of `GET`,while using `POST`,when can using `data` to pass more parameters to `ajax`:

```
var params ={};//define a parameter object
for(var i=0;i<testoutput.length;i++)
{
   var v=document.getElementById(testoutput[i]).value;
   params["testoutput"+i]=v;
}
$.ajax({
  url:your_request_url,
  type:"post",//or get
  data:params,//passing the parameters.
  success:function(data){},
  error:function(){}
});
```